# Cascading KVM switches

Tags: usb, kvm-switch, multiplexing, switching, multiple-computers

I have a not-so-small number of computers (say, 5) which I want to access with a single keyboard, USB and monitor. I can get an 8-port KVM switch, which is a pretty expensive piece of hardware; however, in theory, I should be able to cascade KVM switches: Have one 4-port KVM switch between 2 other KVMs (a 2-port and a 4-port).

Is this doable (with typical off-the-shelf switches and cables)? Has anyone had experience doing this?

**Notes:**

- I'm interested in USB-only for the keyboard and mouse, and either VGA or DVI for the display. Audio and PS/2 connections are irrelevant for me.
- I don't need to be able to switch desktops using special keystrokes. Manual KVM-front-panel switching is good enough.

Comment: *"I should be able to cascade KVM switches"* -- Is this a statement or a question?  In theory, you cannot cascade KVM switches like you can Ethernet switches.  The first KVM switch will intercept all the special keystrokes to switch PCs and not pass them down to lower-tier KVM switches.  This cannot possibly work unless you stick to using the manual front-panel switches.

Comment: @sawdust: Clarified.